# place online to do shared coding for interview

Tags: livechat

I'm giving a phone interview soon, and ideally, I'd like to see the candidate write some code in real time. Can anyone suggest a site where we can both go and he can type while I watch. (I'm behind a fairly strict corporate firewall, so a lot of basic chat services are blocked.)

Comment: I think this question falls into the category of "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" as outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and would suggest reopening the question.

Comment: It wasn't around at the time the question was asked, and since the question is closed I can't submit this as an answer, but as reference for all those others who land here, I'd suggest https://coderpad.io/ , to quote them "CoderPad lets you instantly write and execute code
collaboratively with an interviewee, right in the browser.".

Comment: You can also find a free live tool with execution and all (similar to Coderpad) at [EXLskills](https://exlskills.com/learn-en/talent/interviews) for conducting interviews

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forget where i found this originally but it is quite nifty.
[Seemikecode](http://i.seemikecode.com/)

Comment: Just tried it.  Seems perfect for the type of thing that you are trying to do.  Only think that I'm really missing in it is syntax highlighting.

Comment: hmm... that looks pretty good. only problem is I can't type. something two way would be better.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at http://codeinterview.me. Similar to SeeMikeCode, but also gives the interviewee the option to install an IDE plugin (eclipse/intellij) which allows them to code in their IDE, while you watch in a browser.

Comment: This is better than my answer.  That one is really quite nice.

Answer (score 4):

For 2 people editing a text document (unfortunately, no syntax-highlight - color is for authorship):

http://typewith.me/

- Trivial 1-click, 2-link setup
- Two way editing with colors to identify who contributed each line
- Line numbers
- Indentation level preserved on ENTER
- Undo / Redo / Save / Versions / etc
- Export to Word / PDF / HTML / etc (to attach to HR interview feedback)

For <strike>1 typer and 1 watcher</strike> (with good syntax highlighting):

http://codeinterview.me

- Trivial 1-click, 2-link setup
- Note on 2 typers: if you want both sides to be able to edit (eg, interviewer types in feedback), then both parties should click the "interviewee" link.  This WORKS.
- Plugins for Eclipse / Visual Studio / IDEA - optionally, the user can install an Eclipse plug-in to use that in place of the web editor and get the full fledged editing experience
- Syntax Highlighting (with support for 14 languages, including CoffeScript)
- No export functions (but you can copy / paste)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking to see him compiling and such, why not just use a [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/) or [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) with its live collaboration feature. If you're looking to actually share Visual Studio, you may need a service like [WebEx](http://www.webex.com/) or [Microsoft Office Live Meeting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/live-meeting/).